# How to filter out the first and last entry from a table using RANK?

Tags: sql, group-by, rank

I've this data:

```
Id   Date  Value
'a'  2000  55
'a'  2001  3
'a'  2012  2
'a'  2014  5
'b'  1999  10
'b'  2014  110
'b'  2015  8
'c'  2011  4
'c'  2012  33
```

I want to filter out the **first** and the **last** value (when the table is sorted on the Date column), and only keep the other values. In case there are only two entries, nothing is returned. (Example for Id = 'c')

```
ID   Date  Value
'a'  2001  3
'a'  2012  2
'b'  2014  110
```

I tried to use order by (RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Id] ORDER BY Date ...)) in combination with this article (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/02/sql-server-how-to-retrieve-top-and-bottom-rows-together-using-t-sql/) but I can't get it to work.

[**UPDATE**]

All the 3 answers seem fine. But I'm not a SQL expert, so my question is which one has the fastest performance if the table has around 800000 rows and there a no indexes on any column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table1 b
                  WHERE a.ID = b.ID
                   AND b.Date < a.Date
                  )
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table1 b
                  WHERE a.ID = b.ID
                   AND b.Date > a.Date
                  )
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d8a69/6/0)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number` twice to determine the `min` and `max` dates and then filter accordingly:

```
with cte as (
  select id, [date], value, 
    row_number() over (partition by id order by [date]) minrn,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by [date] desc) maxrn
  from data
  )
select id, [date], value
from cte
where minrn != 1 and maxrn != 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ffd9/3)

---

Here's another approach using `min` and `max` for this without needing to use a ranking function:

```
with cte as (
  select id, min([date]) mindate, max([date]) maxdate
  from data
  group by id 
  )
select * 
from data d
where not exists (
    select 1
    from cte c
    where d.id = c.id and d.[date] in (c.mindate, c.maxdate))
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ffd9/4)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar solution with `row_number` and `count` :

```
SELECT id,
       dat,
       value
FROM   (SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY id
                   ORDER BY dat)    rnk,
               COUNT(*)
                 OVER (
                   partition BY id) cnt
        FROM   @table) t
WHERE  rnk NOT IN( 1, cnt )
```